# Android 12 Device Owner Provisioning with QR code

Tags: kotlin, qr-code, android-pendingintent, android-12, android-device-owner

I have an application, that can be successfully setup as Device Owner on devices up to Android 12 via QR code and now I add two activity like this link for android 12: [Android 12 Device Owner Provisioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70111346/android-12-device-owner-provisioning).
and the device owner setup is completed but when I want to run my app I have this error:(and I don't have any pending intent)

````
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: io.phoenixdev.afw.emm: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.```
````

Answer (score 1):

this is because one or a few of your PendingIntent is created without the Mutability flag. Can you check if you are passing the Mutability flag(either FLAG_MUTABLE or FLAG_IMMUTABLE)? In case you are not modifying the pending intent once created, I would recommend adding FLAG_IMMUTABLE.

Here is the method I use to get flags for Pending Intent so that you don't have to do Android 12 checks everywhere.

```
public static int getPendingIntentFlag(boolean mutable) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        return mutable ? PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE : 
               PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Simply call getPendingIntentFlag(false) for immutable intents like this

```
 val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or 
            Utils.getPendingIntentFlag(false)
  )
```

This way either android 12 or not, you need not worry about this flag.